# Create PHP REST API for add (and view) to database

Tags: php, json, ajax, rest

I'm very new to REST API. I've been watching tutorials etc but with no luck.

I need to POST data (and GET, without form) into a database using a form, and then via ajax send this to my REST API to execute the SQL.

All can be wrong, or just some of it, I have no idea (I used a mix of tutorials).

This is my API (test/api/user_api.php)

```
$host       = " *** ";
$user       = "217129_xt71575";
$dbName     = "217129-test";
$password   = " *** ";

$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $dbName);
mysqli_query($link, "SET NAMES utf8");
mysqli_query($link, "SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

$method     = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
$request    = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], '/'));
$input      = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$table      = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_]+/i', '', array_shift($request)); // I DON'T THINK THIS IS FOR ME?
$key        = array_shift($request)+0; // I DON'T THINK THIS IS FOR ME?
$columns    = array_keys($input);
$values     = array_values($input);

//$columns    = array('email', 'fname', 'lname'); // Used this to try
//$values     = array('j@example.com', 'jonna', 'hedlund'); // Used this to try

$set = '';
for ($i=0;$i<count($columns);$i++) {
    $set .= ($i > 0 ? ', ' : '' ). '' . $columns[$i] . ' = ?';
}

switch ($method) {
    case 'GET':
        show_users($link);
        break;
    case 'POST':
        insert_user($link, $set, $values);
}

function show_users($link) {
    $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM test_users");
    $rows   = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }

    return json_encode($rows);
}

function insert_user($link, $set, $values) {
    $stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO test_users SET $set");
    $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $values[0], $values[1], $values[2]);
    $stmt->execute() OR die();

        // THEN return something?
}
```

This is my ajaxfile (test/app.js)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var form = document.getElementById("userform");

    $('.add_user').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var data = {};
        for(var i = 0, ii = form.length; i < ii; i++){
            var input = form[i];
            if(input.name) {
                data[input.name] = input.value;
            }
        }

        addUser(data);

    });

    function addUser(data) {

        var check = JSON.stringify(data);

        alert(check);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/api/user_api.php",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            contentType: "application, json; charset=utf-8",
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data, status, jqXHR) { // I'm only used to using 'text' here..
                alert('success');
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, status) { // I'm only used to using 'text' here..
                console.log(jqXHR);
                alert('fail: ' + status.code);
            }
        });
    }

});
```

And finally my "form" (test/index.php)

```
<form action="" id="userform">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email">
    <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="fname">
    <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="lname">
</form>
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="add_user">send</button>
```

I've tried so hard to understand the logic of all this but with no luck, do you have any suggestions? The thing that's really new to me is REST API and working with JSON.

Comment: There's two bits of code labelled `I DON'T THINK THIS IS FOR ME?` - I would probably agree. I would guess you need the `Used this to try` lines, and delete the four lines above this.

Comment: Mostly we can't tell you what code to write - we can make suggestions of course, but only you know what you want this to do. The trick here is to learn  the art of debugging - you have a good structure, so you just need to check the values you are receiving in the AJAX op at various points, and where you find a value is not correct, work out why. You could use `file_put_contents($path, $var)` to save values for examination.

Comment: thank you for your answers, I started over and are using an "regular array" instead of json for my post data, so I just ditched this whole idea, I don't know if what I do now is proper REST-API since I don't use correct URI, but hey it's working so I'm semi-happy about that. @halfer